# Booster pump connect to same line

Tags: plumbing, water-pressure

I got a [water pressure booster pump](https://www.leaderpumpshop.com/Products/BOOSTER-SYSTEM/ECOMATIC/ECOMATIC-110.aspx) for my home and don't have an accessible return line. My inlet is from a garden hose line tap. Could I return to the same line using a T fitting and check valves on each side or would this overload the pipe?

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand your question. A booster will increase your pressure but why do you need a return line? Usually booster pumps are in line with cistern or tank and when turned on the pressure increases. If you are pulling from the same point you are returning the water nothing will be gained.

Comment: I am assuming I have a check valve coming from the water meter. I want to pressurize the lines in the house. I don't have cistern tank, yet.